# Merging two multiindexes together in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two multiindexes which I want to merge together on the indexes. 
Below I want to merge on `Cif` and `ye` and have both 0 columns in the `al_staff` dataframe.

```
al_staff=pd.merge(new.reset_index(), staff_cost_sum.reset_index(), on=['Cif', 'ye'], how='inner').set_index(['Cif','ye'])
```

I reset the index and specified what columns to merge on, and defined what columns should be in the new index. Nothing is returned.

The 'new' dataframe is a combination of several dataframes similar to `staff_sum`, but they have the same index, `Cif` and `ye`, per the below:

```
new=pd.concat([staff_cost_sum, sub_cost_sum, consum_cost_sum, soft_cost_sum]).sum(level=['Cif','ye'])
new.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

It seems that the data types are being changed in the process, as the new dataframe has `Cif` and `ye` set as object types and `staff_cost_sum` remains as `int64` data types.

How can I retain the same data type of the `Cif` and `ye` column in the 'new' dataframe? It doesn't matter to me what data types they are, as this is all I need to do (so there are no future ramifications), but I'd rather know how to edit the code examples below to do this rather than do a workaround solution. Any thoughts appreciate though.

The two multiindex data sets are below.

```
Cif     ye  0
277     13  519297.676200
        14  770372.973000
        15  63046.854000
312     13  21292.546058
322     14  60154.098500
361     13  78735.072000

Cif     ye  0
277     13  444597.411500
        14  484438.682500
312     13  21292.546058
322     14  60154.098500
361     13  78735.072000
        16  35333.400000




new.reset_index().info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2101 entries, 0 to 2100
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Cif    2101 non-null object
ye     2101 non-null object
0      2101 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 49.3+ KB


staff_cost_sum.reset_index().info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1899 entries, 0 to 1898
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Cif    1899 non-null int64
ye     1899 non-null int64
0      1899 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 44.6 KB
```

Intended output:

```
                  0_x            0_y
Cif ye                              
277 13  444597.411500  519297.676200
    14  484438.682500  770372.973000
312 13   21292.546058   21292.546058
322 14   60154.098500   60154.098500
361 13   78735.072000   78735.072000
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Both 0 columns, in separate columns, so it would create columns 0_x and 0_y edit: and the index being 'Cif' and 'ye'

Answer (score 0):

IIUC. use `join` to join on  multiindexed rows:

```
df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_x', lsuffix='_y', how='inner')
```

Output:

```
                  0_y            0_x
Cif ye                              
277 13  519297.676200  444597.411500
    14  770372.973000  484438.682500
312 13   21292.546058   21292.546058
322 14   60154.098500   60154.098500
361 13   78735.072000   78735.072000
```

Or

```
df2.merge(df1, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='inner')
```

output:

```
                  0_x            0_y
Cif ye                              
277 13  444597.411500  519297.676200
    14  484438.682500  770372.973000
312 13   21292.546058   21292.546058
322 14   60154.098500   60154.098500
361 13   78735.072000   78735.072000
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the second code in my original question is making 'Cif' and 'ye' to change data types, so my question is how to prevent that from happening so that the first code would work, as with the first code and your two examples, I am essentially trying to join data on data with different data types.

Comment: Can you post the .info() for both dataframes or the code to generate the dataframes with the different dtypes.

Comment: edit: I've put the info() at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: Okay, post staff_cost_sum.index and new.index also.   I don't see any different dtypes yet.

Comment: Ah ok, edited it again, shown reset_index and you can see the different data types, object and int64.

Comment: Can you now posted what your expected output should look like with these dataframes?  Not just the description but the actual values.

Comment: Exactly what you've provided in your answer. I will add that to the original question too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165088/discussion-between-scott-boston-and-iwan).